# ASP.NET AJAX Deserialization

Tags: javascript, asp.net, serialization, asp.net-ajax

For some reason, in ASP.NET AJAX, when I do this:

```
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize({attachToValidators:true});
```

This is the result:

```
"{"attachToValidators":true}"
```

I try reversing the result:

```
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize("{\"attachToValidators\":true}");
```

or:

```
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize("{attachToValidators:true}");
```

I get this result:

Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.
Parameter name: data

Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer posted here, though in 3.5, it was working great for me, I didn't need JSON.parse, so I don't know quite what happened: http://forums.asp.net/t/1631638.aspx

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to deserialize it *to*? This is how JavaScriptSerializer works, for deserialization:

```
public class ValidatorInfo
{
  public bool attachToValidators { get; set; }
}

public void yourFunction()
{
  var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

  ValidatorInfo info = js.Deserialize<ValidatorInfo>("{\"attachToValidators\":true}");

  // True.
  info.attachToValidators == true;
}
```

In your question, you're serializing an anonymous type, so you get away with not having an underlying type to serialize.  That doesn't work on the way back in though.

If you need more dynamic behavior, Json.Net provides something like that with its LINQ implementation.

Comment: You should be using json2.js on the client-side.  In later browsers, that will leverage the faster, more secure browser-native JSON.parse and JSON.stringify features. In older ones, it will degrade to JavaScript-based code similar to what Sys.Serialization uses.

Comment: OK, but I don't understand why code previously working is now failing on me, since it's MS's implementation, unless I'm missing a setup reference in .NET 4.0...